# WP is not allowing me to post Macintosh .pages documents to my blog

Tags: editor

I'm completely green when it comes to website development, therefore, if you do have an answer for me could you please explain it in laymen's terms.

My problem:
I just created a blog post using .pages, this document includes illustrations and a preselected design layout as well as a couple pages of content. I think it's just a matter of WP not recognizing the format. When I go to the post and try to add the .pages document with the media upload I get this message...

> "Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons."

When I just copy and paste the each page individually into the post it views fine but when I publish and update the post the material is only viewed as a blue square with a question mark.

I've read about similar issues experienced by others but it was concerning multi sites and I don't believe that my webpage is a multisite. See www.suttonsez.com.
When I go to my dashboard and look under Settings there isn't an option for adding extensions.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

> When I just copy and paste the each page individually into the post it views fine but when I publish and update the post the material is only viewed as a blue square with a question mark.

That's your answer. You should create content *within* WordPress, not try to upload arbitrary files from some other application. Content management systems such as WordPress really aren't designed such that users create text documents (in MS Word, or iWork, etc.) and then upload those documents; rather, you create the content directly within the CMS.

What you *do have* to upload are the images to be used in the content. And once uploaded, they have to be inserted using the "Insert into Post" button.

Answer (score 1):

Blog posts need to be text or html. [A `.pages` file is neither](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/pages). While I have never used Pages, it looks to be more of a Word Processor or an Illustrator/InDesign-like application (which don't work online either). This isn't just a WordPress issue. Even if you got it uploaded it won't be viewable. The blue square and question mark usually indicates a 'bad' character, which isn't surprising given that you are pasting from that software. You are using the wrong tool for the job, unfortunately, the right tool really being WordPress itself, as per @chip-bennett answer.

Try using the "Paste From Word" tool in the visual editor. Look for an icon that looks like a little clipboard with a "W" over it.

> [image]

Look around in Pages and see if it will export HTML.

I don't know if either option will work very well, but those are your best shots, probably.